# When will ECMAScript v 6 become standard

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I'm wondering when ECMAScript v 6 will become more than a draft, and become the new standard.  Going to the [ECMA website (section 262)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) still shows edition 5.1 as being the latest, which was released in June 2011.

Note: *(I plan on doing a talk on ECMA 262 edition 5.1 in the next couple of months and I'm hoping I'm not talking about out-dated material :)*

Comment: Would someone who has voted to close care to explain how this is either not constructive or too localized?

Comment: @djechlin    http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110048/133242

Comment: I feel the only reason you closed it was because of the "I plan on doing a talk" note....

Comment: Nope. I voted to close for the reasons in the linked Meta discussion.

Comment: Don't worry about it; ES5 is not outdated material. The version before that was released in 1999, so 2009-2011 (ES5-ES5.1) is pretty darn recent. In fact, most developers still work in ES3 (in part because IE8 doesn't support ES5).

Comment: Why not have a "localized" tag that indicates you acknowledge the question is localized, and still wish to ask / get answers. Likewise, users interested in participating in the question too "consent" to take part in a "localized" question. Preferable to policing and closing good questions.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As of June 2015: **here it is**!

> [http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/**6.0**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)

---

As of [June 2014](https://twitter.com/awbjs/status/474662357516689410):

> [The GA will vote on approving it as a Ecma standard at their **June 2015** meeting.](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts)

---

At the time of writing (March 2013):

> A sixth edition of the standard is currently under development with a target date of December 2013 for completion.

http://ecma-international.org/memento/TC39-M.htm

Comment: Delayed to December 2014 according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#ECMAScript_Harmony_.286th_Edition.29).

Comment: Delayed again to June 2015, though you can already use many of the features today with [traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler).

Comment: There is also [Babel](http://babeljs.io/), see the [FAQ](https://babeljs.io/docs/faq/#how-does-babel-differ-from-other-transpilers-) for differences to other transpilers.

Comment: Ok, so it's now June 2015. Am googling for an update. Please comment here if you already know whether publication of the ECMAScript 6 standard has happened.

Comment: @arcseldon [the GA June 2015 meeting isn't until the 17th.](http://www.ecma-international.org/memento/Ecma_meeting_calendar.htm) Cool your jets `:)`

Comment: @MattBall - Thank you! One of the disappointments of 2014 was the postponement of ES6. Guess I can wait another day ;)

Comment: @arcseldon two days now. But who's counting?