# How to make JSLint happy about references to Uint8Array in Node.js code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jslint

When running JSLint on my Node.js code it says that *"'Uint8Array' [was used before it was defined](http://jslinterrors.com/a-was-used-before-it-was-defined)."* The [Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) puts it in the "Standard built-in objects" category in ECMAScript 6, and it's supported in all the major browsers. When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking in PyCharm it opens the definition in `HTML5.js`, and the code runs fine, so it definitely does exist in the relevant context.

Am I missing some sort of import or JavaScript idiom, or is this a bug in JSLint?

I've worked around it with `/*global Uint8Array*/` for now.

**Edit:** [Pull request with fix.](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/pull/163)

Comment: Did you `/*jslint node:true */`? Though I think you're really talking about `/*jslint browser:true*/` here, perhaps?

Comment: @ruffin [Nope](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html). This is server code, and definitely does *not* have a browser context available. Anyway, I tried `browser` in my confusion, and it didn't work either.

Comment: Well, it doesn't complain about other functions in the same part of the ECMAScript standard built-in objects such as [`ParseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: You're saying that anything in a "standard built-in objects" category shouldn't need a jslint specific context declared? Hrm. To [jslint's code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L579), I guess. It's not there. If you think it belongs in `"the global names that are provided by the ECMAScript standard,"` then it's worth a post on [the JSLint Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/communities/104441363299760713736).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your answer, if you believe the source:

[When will ECMAScript v 6 become standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640233/when-will-ecmascript-v-6-become-standard#comment39096025_15640290)

> Delayed again to June 2015, though you can already use many of the
>   features today with traceur. –  urish Aug 4 at 13:49

And that ECMAScript 6 is still a draft (as of 20141023 anyhow) is confirmed on the [Uint8Array page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array#Specifications) you linked to, and [here](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#table-45) as well.

Forget what I said about posting on a post on [the JSLint Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/communities/104441363299760713736).  ;^)

Interesting and fun goose chase, though.

Comment: Nice research. It *is* available in Node.js though, so I'll ask for it to be included anyway. Node.js is browser independent, after all.

Comment: If that's the case, I think it's probably fair to ask that it's put into the `node` array ([here, currently line 551](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L551)).

Comment: Good luck getting the `global_extractors/node.js` in. He keeps a pretty clean repo. That's an, "If that makes it in, I'll eat my hat," situation. More hopeful about the updated node array [to object]. ;^)